# Scroll bar keep returning to top in infinite scroll -React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, graphql, progressive-web-apps

I have used following code in my component to load new data when scrolling.But when new page of data is loaded the scroll bar keeps returning to the top.I'm using this for Magento PWA with react.

```
const Category = props => {
    const {id} = props;
    const classes = mergeClasses(defaultClasses, props.classes);
    const [paginationValues, paginationApi] = usePagination();
    const {currentPage, totalPages} = paginationValues;
    const {setCurrentPage, setTotalPages} = paginationApi;

    const [selectedPageSize, setPageSize] = useState(40);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
    function handlePageSize() {
        setPageNumber(pageNumber+1)
    }
    const sortProps = useSort();
    const [currentSort] = sortProps;

    const previousSort = useRef(currentSort);

    const pageControl = {
        currentPage,
        setPage: setCurrentPage,
        totalPages
    };

    const [runQuery, queryResponse] = useLazyQuery(GET_CATEGORY,{fetchPolicy:'cache-first'});
    const {loading, error, data} = queryResponse;
    const {search} = useLocation();

    const bqueryResponsee = useQuery(
        GET_ATTRIBUTES
    );
    let battributedata = '';

    // Keep track of the search terms so we can tell when they change.
    const previousSearch = useRef(search);

    // Get "allowed" filters by intersection of schema and aggregations
    const {data: introspectionData} = useQuery(FILTER_INTROSPECTION);

    // Create a type map we can reference later to ensure we pass valid args
    // to the graphql query.
    // For example: { category_id: 'FilterEqualTypeInput', price: 'FilterRangeTypeInput' }
    const filterTypeMap = useMemo(() => {
        const typeMap = new Map();
        if (introspectionData) {
            introspectionData.__type.inputFields.forEach(({name, type}) => {
                typeMap.set(name, type.name);
            });
        }
        return typeMap;
    }, [introspectionData]);

    // Run the category query immediately and whenever its variable values change.
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', infiniteScroll);
        // Wait until we have the type map to fetch product data.
        if (!filterTypeMap.size) {
            return;
        }

        const filters = getFiltersFromSearch(search);
        const newFilters = {};

        newFilters['category_id'] = {eq: String(id)};

        filters.forEach((values, key) => {
            newFilters[key] = getFilterInput(values, filterTypeMap.get(key));
        });

        runQuery({
            variables: {
                currentPage: Number(pageNumber),
                id: Number(id),
                filters: newFilters,
                pageSize: Number(selectedPageSize),
                sort: {[currentSort.sortAttribute]: currentSort.sortDirection}
            }
        });
        window.scrollTo({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }, [
        currentPage,
        currentSort,
        filterTypeMap,
        id,
        selectedPageSize,
        runQuery,
        search,
        pageNumber
    ]);

    const totalPagesFromData = data
        ? Math.ceil(data.category.product_count/selectedPageSize)
        : null;
    useEffect(() => {
        setTotalPages(totalPagesFromData);
        return () => {
            setTotalPages(null);
        };
    }, [setTotalPages, totalPagesFromData]);

    // If we get an error after loading we should try to reset to page 1.
    // If we continue to have errors after that, render an error message.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (error && !loading && currentPage !== 1) {
            setCurrentPage(1);
        }
    }, [currentPage, error, loading, setCurrentPage]);

    // Reset the current page back to one (1) when the search string, filters
    // or sort criteria change.
    useEffect(() => {
        // We don't want to compare page value.
        const prevSearch = new URLSearchParams(previousSearch.current);
        const nextSearch = new URLSearchParams(search);
        prevSearch.delete('page');
        nextSearch.delete('page');

        if (
            prevSearch.toString() !== nextSearch.toString() ||
            previousSort.current.sortAttribute.toString() !==
            currentSort.sortAttribute.toString() ||
            previousSort.current.sortDirection.toString() !==
            currentSort.sortDirection.toString()
        ) {
            // The search term changed.
            setCurrentPage(1);
            // And update the ref.
            previousSearch.current = search;
            previousSort.current = currentSort;
        }
    }, [currentSort, previousSearch, search, setCurrentPage]);
 
    if (error && currentPage === 1 && !loading) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
            console.error(error);
        }
        return <div>Data Fetch Error</div>;
    }

    // Show the loading indicator until data has been fetched.
    if (totalPagesFromData === null) {
        return fullPageLoadingIndicator;
    }


    if (typeof bqueryResponsee.data !== "undefined" && !bqueryResponsee.loading) {
        battributedata = bqueryResponsee.data.customAttributeMetadata.items[0].attribute_options;
    } else {
        battributedata = [];
    }



    const count = totalPagesFromData ? totalPagesFromData : null;
    const galleries = [];
    if (count && count >= 1) {
        for (let i =1;i<=pageNumber;i++) {
            galleries.push(
                <section className={classes.gallery}>
                <Gallery searchItems={null} ID={1}
                         newSort={{[currentSort.sortAttribute]: currentSort.sortDirection}}
                         newFilters={newFiltersLazy}
                         currentPage={i} categoryId={id} pageSize={40} introspectionData={introspectionData}
                         battributedata={battributedata}/>
                 </section>
            )
        }
    }

    function infiniteScroll(){
        console.log(Math.ceil((window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop)/100)*100,Math.ceil((document.documentElement.offsetHeight*8/10)/100)*100)

        // End of the document reached?
        if ( Math.ceil((window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop)/100)*100
            >= Math.ceil((document.documentElement.offsetHeight*8/10)/100)*100){
            handlePageSize()
        }
    }
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Meta name="description" content={metaDescription}/>
            <CategoryContent
                totalPagesFromData={totalPagesFromData}
                categoryId={id}
                classes={classes}
                data={loading ? null : data}
                pageControl={pageControl}
                sortProps={sortProps}
                onSelectSize={handlePageSize}
                battributedata={battributedata}
                selectedPageSize={selectedPageSize}
                galleries={galleries}
                newSort={{[currentSort.sortAttribute]: currentSort.sortDirection}}
                newFilters={newFiltersLazy}
                introspectionData={introspectionData}
                pageNumber={pageNumber}
            />
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

What I did here is created a new array galleries and the Gallery component in each page increment while scrolling and inside Gallery the items will be created.Problem is the scroll bar keep returning to the top in each increment.Please help

Comment: Create a sample code in stackblitz or any other online IDE